# How can I format a new string from Rake's FileList?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm writing a rakefile and need to run mstest against several test dll's at once. I need it to run mstest only once because I need only one TRX file. In order to run mstest against more than one test dll, I need to be able to add several instances of `/testcontainer:some.test.dll` in the same command. Here's my current rake task:

```
task :tests do
    testDlls = FileList.new("#{BUILD_PATH}/*.Specs.dll")
sh "#{MSTEST_PATH} /testcontainer:#{testDlls}"      
end
```

For an example, testDlls has test1.dll, test2.dll, and test3.dll. The above task outputs:

```
c:\msbuild\msbuild.exe /testcontainer:test1.dll test2.dll test3.dll
```

What I need is:

```
c:\msbuild\msbuild.exe /testcontainer:test1.dll /testcontainer:test2.dll /testcontainer:test3.dll
```

How can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```
require 'shellwords'
task :tests do
    testDlls = FileList.new("#{BUILD_PATH}/*.Specs.dll")
    ary = Shellwords.shellwords(testDlls.to_s)
    sh "#{MSTEST_PATH} #{ary.map {|dll| '/testcontainer:' + dll}.join(' ')"      
end
```

Comment: It looks promising, but I'm getting another error. Your 4th line throws this:
undefined method `scan' for #<Rake::FileList:0x5162d0>
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/shellwords.rb:35:in `shellsplit'